# Issue in calculating the distance from point to the nearest edge of a polygon using python

Tags: python

I want to calculate the distance from each point within a polygon to the nearest edge of the polygon. The code I am using is shown below. But, the results does not show the distances from each point to the nearest edge of the polygon. I am also relatively new to python language.

Please see the image showing the points and the polygon. [image]

Can somebody help me to figure out why its not showing the distances from each point to nearest edge of the polygon.? Its only showing the distance for one point. Point number 0 and 1 are located on the same location and also 4 and 5 are located in the same place.

Please see the link to download the shape files. 
https://bft.usu.edu/klvzz

First, I need to intersect the points within 100 meters within the polygon line and then calculate the distances using my code below.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

poly_Br = gpd.read_file("/home/User/Documents/arcgis_dist/input_files/Br_poly.shp")
point = gpd.read_file("/home/User/Documents/arcgis_dist/input_files/geoch_centroid.shp")
d1 = poly_Br.exterior.distance(point)
print(d1)

0    626.283954
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4           NaN
5           NaN
dtype: float64
[Finished in 0.595s]
```